# How to navigate between pages in wpf correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Switching between C# WPF EntityFramework pages

I'm switching between pages in wpf and the logic of my application is like this: I have a login page and an example of a new HomePage page is created from this page and I pass the user id of the one who logged in to the constructor, I do it like this:

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((LoginTextBox.Text != "") && (PasswordTextBox.Text != ""))
            {
                using (var db = new colledgeDepartmentEntities())
                {
                    var user = (from u in db.users where
                               u.login == LoginTextBox.Text && u.password == PasswordTextBox.Text select u).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        int userId = user.idUser;
                        //PageHelper.main.FrameMain.Navigate(new HomePage(userId));
                        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new HomePage(userId));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Логин или пароль введен не верно");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

From the HomePage I go to another page and the menu of this page I have a transition field back to the HomePage and I need to pass the user id of the one who logged in there, but I do not know how to pass it there and I can't make this parameter optional in the constructor either.
I am a student and do not know how to do it right, I will be glad of any criticism and suggestions on how to do it in my situation/ how to do it right.

```
PageHelper.main.FrameMain.Navigate(new HomePage(userId)); - the variant that I originally have 
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new HomePage(userId)); - the variant that I found on the Internet
```

Answer (score 0):

I would either introduce a `ViewModel` to hold relevant data for the `HomePage` view. Or introduce a `UserService` to hold user related data all across the app.

However since you said you are still learning I could also offer
a quick and dirty solution without any new concepts. You could create a public property on the `HomePage` and set it from the click event.

```
 var homepage = new HomePage()
 hompage.UserId = userId;
 this.NavigationService.Navigate(homepage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well store the data in a static application service class that you can easily access from all your pages and classes, e.g.:

```
public static class ApplicationService
{
    public static int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

**LoginButton_Click:**

```
ApplicationService.UserId = userId;
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new HomePage());
```

**Access from another page/class:**

```
int userId = ApplicationService.UserId;
```

Then you don't have to bother passing it around between pages as you navigate through the application.

Answer (score 0):

In your WPF application, you want to pass the user ID from one page to another when navigating between them. You're on the right track with passing the user ID to the `HomePage` constructor when navigating from the login page. To pass additional data between pages in WPF, you can use various approaches. Here's a common approach using navigation parameters:

1. **Create a NavigationService Class (Optional)**: It can be helpful to create a navigation service class to manage navigation throughout your application. This is especially useful if you plan to navigate from multiple places in your application. Here's a simplified example:

```cs
public static class NavigationService
{
    private static Frame _mainFrame;

    public static void Initialize(Frame mainFrame)
    {
        _mainFrame = mainFrame;
    }

    public static void NavigateToHomePage(int userId)
    {
        _mainFrame.Navigate(new HomePage(userId));
    }
}
```

2. **Initialize NavigationService (App.xaml.cs)**: In your `App.xaml.cs` or at the application's entry point, initialize the navigation service with your main frame. This should be done once when your application starts:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // Initialize the navigation service with the main frame
        NavigationService.Initialize(MainWindow.FrameMain);

        // Other startup logic
    }
}
```

3. **Navigating from Login Page**: In your login page's click event handler, use the navigation service to navigate to the `HomePage` while passing the user ID:

```cs
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((LoginTextBox.Text != "") && (PasswordTextBox.Text != ""))
    {
        using (var db = new colledgeDepartmentEntities())
        {
            var user = (from u in db.users
                        where u.login == LoginTextBox.Text && u.password == PasswordTextBox.Text
                        select u).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                int userId = user.idUser;
                NavigationService.NavigateToHomePage(userId);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Логин или пароль введен не верно");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. **Passing User ID to Other Pages**: When you navigate to other pages and need to pass the user ID, you can extend the navigation service to accommodate this. For instance, if you need to navigate to a page and pass the user ID:

```cs
public static void NavigateToSomePage(int userId)
{
    _mainFrame.Navigate(new SomePage(userId));
}
```

By following this approach, you centralize the navigation logic and make it easier to pass data between different pages in your WPF application.